# All my devices are incompatible with lower API then compileSdkVersion 26

Tags: java, android

I already almost done in the development the apps.

I'm using android studio 3.1 But when I test using the lower API my apps doesn't works even I already set the minSdkVersion 15.

I hope you can give me some advise on this matter.

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fadhli.picbetaversionstable"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            postprocessing {
                removeUnusedCode false
                removeUnusedResources false
                obfuscate false
                optimizeCode false
                proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
//    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: target sdk sould match compile sdk

Comment: Didnt have anything error. The apps run smothly using API 26 but when run using lower api. For example api 22, the apps cannot open. Unfortunately, PICBetaVersion stopped.

Comment: I changed targetSdkVersion to 26 still same. Doesn't work for the lower API

Comment: One of your libraries do not support >API 26. Check their prerequisites if you are using external libraries, or use support repository which will give backwards compatibility till API 7.